# Why isn't my rake command working? I've posted what happens in my MAC OSX terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rakefile

As you can see below, I ran rake db:mirgate and the errors below spit out. This happens even though I have a rakefile in my application.

```
Nate-Air:proj Nate$ rake db:migrate

rake aborted!

No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, 
Rakefile.rb)

/Users/Nate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

/Users/Nate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'

/Users/Nate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Nate-Air:proj Nate$
```

Comment: most problem with this is the user not cd apps_folder

Comment: what do you suggest I do?

Comment: check if the Rakefile exists in your program folder.

Comment: after  you did  rails new apps_folder, before run rake db:migrate type cd apps_folder make sure you right inside your working folder

Comment: the rakefile exists under my project "Nate" which is currently open. That is where I am operating the rake command.

Comment: maybe I should generate a new rakefile? Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Check the Rakefile. Type `ls`.

Comment: ls what? when I type "ls" nothing happens. I get this:                    
Nate-Air: proj Nate$ ls
Nate-Air: proj Nate$

Answer (score 1):

`ls`command result is nothing, it is not project root.
You have to stay the root directory of your project.
Move to your project root.

How to create a generic rails project:

`1. rails new some_project
2. cd some_project
3. bundle install
4. bundle exec rake db:migrate`